# Dividing Two Sums

Tags: calculus, summation

I have three sets of data points, let's say...$\{1,2\}\cup\{3,4\}\cup\{5,6\}$.

Now suppose that I want to sum up the first point in each, and divide it by the sum of the quotients of each pair, e.g. $(1+3+4)\div(1\div2+3\div4+5\div6)$.

I can call the first element $a$ and the second element $b$ and write the equation like this:
$$\sum_{i=s}^n a_i \div \sum_{i=s}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}$$

However, I don't know if this can be made more readable.  I know of the property of sums shown below...
$$\sum_{i=s}^m\sum_{j=t}^n {a_i}{c_j} = \sum_{i=s}^m a_i \cdot \sum_{j=t}^n c_j$$
...but I don't know if there is a parallel application when division is involved. Can this be condensed at all?

Comment: I personally don't see anything to nicely simplify it. It might look just a little better if written $$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=s}^na_i}{\sum\limits_{i=s}^n\frac{a_i}{b_i}}$$

Comment: At best you'd have $$\sum_{i=s}^{m} \frac{a_i}{\sum_{j=t}^{n}\frac{a_j}{b_j}}$$ Your addition/multiplication combination works because of the distributive property; can't quite break up quotients like that though, at least not without tedious PFD that likely isn't worth the effort.